# Linux find with prune and negation

Tags: linux, shell, find

I want to grep all files in a directory except for

- subdirectories of `lib`
- images (`png` and `jpg`)

I'm doing it in a shell script, passing the arguments to `grep`, no problem.

This command excludes the subdirectories of `lib`

```
find src \
  -name lib -prune -o \
  -type f -exec grep -P "$@" {} +
```

and this one excludes the images

```
find src \
  ! -name "*.jpg" ! -name ".png" \
  -type f -exec grep -P "$@" {} +
```

Put together as

```
find src \
  -name lib -prune -o \
  ! -name "*.jpg" ! -name ".png" \
  -type f -exec grep -P "$@" {} +
```

it fails to exclude the images. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Works for me. You can also try with `-o -name "*.jpg" -prune`.

Comment: Please vote for closing as "simple typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails to exclude png images because you left out the `*` in `-name "*.png"`.

Comment: I can't believe it!!! I triple checked and copied it from the working version. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

A generally useful approach is to filter results via grep after a pipe, this decreases complexity in the original command, so:

find [simplified find options] |  egrep -v ".jpg|.png"

Comment: ... and increases the running time